# Finding the average of a series of numbers in a sublist

Tags: list, average, sublist

I am trying to find the average of a series of numbers within a sublist. So far I have code that will successfully average each number at the same index position thus:

```
list_1 = [[1,3,5], [7,4,9], [3,6,2], [5,4,7]]
average = [round(sum(x)/float(len(x)),0) for x in zip(*list_1)]
print (average)
```

Which returns the values [4.0, 4.0, 6.0] being the averages of 1+7+3+5/4 etc

However what I want to achieve is the average of each set of numbers eg 1+3+5/3, 7+4+9/3 etc so that the averages [3.0, 14.0, 10.0, 11.0] are returned. i can't find anything that will allow me to enumerate each subset before moving on to the next.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `zip()` method, which is joining all your lists. Get rid of it and your problems will all go away.

```
average = [sum(x)/len(x) for x in list_1]
```

Comment: Some things are just too simple - that was me over-thinking the problem! Thanks